# Find element in list Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
$('.item_has_children a').first().css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="item_has_children">
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item_has_children">
        <a href="#">Category 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to color the first links : "category 1" and "category 2".

I try but only the first link is coloring red.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you're calling `.first()` to get the first element and you're confused it's only colouring the first element?

Answer (score 3):

You can use immediate child selector `>` to target immediate anchor elements both using CSS and jquery.

**Using CSS:**

```
.item_has_children > a{color:red;}
```

**Working Demo using CSS:**

```css
.item_has_children>a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item_has_children">
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item_has_children">
    <a href="#">Category 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
$('.item_has_children > a').css("color","red");
```

**Working Demo using Jquery:**

```js
$('.item_has_children > a').css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="item_has_children">
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item_has_children">
        <a href="#">Category 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a href="#">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use javascript for this, you can use CSS.(*Better Performance and User Experience*)

```
.item_has_children > a {
    color: red;
}
```

`>` here will select [**direct children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) of `.item_has_children` element.

Demo:

```css
.item_has_children>a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item_has_children"> <a href="#">Category 1</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="menu_item"> <a href="#">Hello</a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu_item"> <a href="#">Hello</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item_has_children"> <a href="#">Category 2</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="menu_item"> <a href="#">Hello</a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu_item"> <a href="#">Hello</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

operator `>` is used for select immediate started DOM element of selector.

```
$("li.item_has_children > a").css("color","red");
```